# How to press Enter key programmatically on textArea and form inputs with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using an On-Screen-Keyboard for browsers with kiosk mode. The problem I've realized is that the Enter Key is not working because the dispatchEvent and KeyboardEvent used are failing.

Code like this has no effect:

```
  focusElement.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent("beforeinput", {"key": "Enter", "shiftKey": false, "keyCode": 13}));
  focusElement.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {"key": "Enter", "shiftKey": false, "keyCode": 13}));
  focusElement.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent("keyup", {"key": "Enter", "shiftKey": false, "keyCode": 13}));
```

As a workaround, I'm checking if an input belongs to a **Form**, in order to submit the form by calling the submit function of the form element, or if the element is a **textarea** to split the text and try to move the scroll to the correct position (Yeah, I know...).

For better undestanding, check this [codepen](https://codepen.io/dani-rj/pen/qBYYwQp?editors=1010) which try to simulate an Enter key press every 3 seconds.

I don't know if I'm using badly the dispatch and keyboard Events but, How can I avoid these ugly workarounds?

Comment: Not possible. Event dispatching emulates _events_, not user's actions.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+press+enter+programatically+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.